# AWS Cognito update multiple users attributes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to find a way to update multiple users (specific attribute) at once without having to make multiple calls to cognito. Just in one call. 
Is there a way to pass a list of users to get updated? I couldn't find anything related in the aws docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do so. You can see the list of all available Userpool API calls [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html). As seen there, we have only 2 update APIs - [UpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateUserAttributes.html) & [AdminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) and both of them update one user at a time. You can submit a feature request for such an API call with AWS Support though. Looks like an interesting use case.